# Display Authors Comments on Profile Page

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, comments, author, author-template

I am trying to display authors comments on their profile page (author.php), however both codes I tried seem to display everyone's comments. Also the second code is suppose to link to the specific comment, but instead it does nothing. Also the comments id is already added to the comments output and it prints fine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
// Method 1
<ul class="authpcom">
<?php
$author_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ); 

$args = array(
    'author_email' => $author_email
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo('<a href=" ' . get_permalink($comment->post_ID) . ' " rel="external nofollow" title=" ' . $title . ' ">' .$title . '</a><br />' . $comment->comment_date . '<br /><li>' . $comment->comment_content . '</li>');
endforeach;
?>
</ul>


// Method 2
<?php   $comments = get_comments(); ?>
<ul id="recent_comments">
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
<li><p><strong><?php
        $title = get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID);
        echo get_avatar( $comment, '45' );
echo strip_tags($comment->comment_author); ?></strong>&nbsp;commented on <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID); ?>#comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" rel="external nofollow" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"> <?php echo $title; ?></a>: <?php echo wp_html_excerpt( $comment->comment_content, 45 ); ?> (...)</p></li>
<?php }  ?>
</ul>
```

Used on comment output divs -

```
$comment->comment_ID
```

> object(WP_User)#345 (7) { ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#344 (10) {
>   ["ID"]=> string(1) "2" ["user_login"]=> string(6) "agent1"
>   ["user_pass"]=> string(34) "$P$BXUSPFSBfmyIrjZ2YUnbIs1GwjkdH50"
>   ["user_nicename"]=> string(6) "agent1" ["user_email"]=> string(19)
>   "agent1@homekast.com" ["user_url"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["user_registered"]=> string(19) "2015-07-25 10:33:27"
>   ["user_activation_key"]=> string(0) "" ["user_status"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["display_name"]=> string(9) "John Paul" } ["ID"]=> int(2) ["caps"]=>
>   array(1) { ["agent"]=> bool(true) } ["cap_key"]=> string(15)
>   "tr_capabilities" ["roles"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "agent" }
>   ["allcaps"]=> array(2) { ["read"]=> bool(true) ["agent"]=> bool(true)
>   } ["filter"]=> NULL }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to use here is the [WP_Comment_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) function.

So on the `author.php` page, you can easily get the author info and ID as followed:

```
// get author info
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));

// set ID
$user_id = $curauth->ID;
```

Then we add the user ID in the query arguments array:

```
$args = array(
    'user_id' => $user_id, // comments by this user only
    'status' => 'approve',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post'
);
```

And finally we hit the arguments in the `wp_comment_query()`:

```
// The Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

// Comment Loop
if ( $comments ) {
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
        echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No comments found.';
}
```

As an added *bonus*, I investigated how pagination works with `wp_comment_query()` for not long ago and [offer a good solution here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184449/wp-comment-query-pagination-delving-into-the-unknown/184451#184451). It was a little bit of a fiddle-niddle to make it work.

EDIT:

A better way to get the author ID is simply with (props @Pieter):

```
$user_id = get_queried_object_id();
```

Comment: You can get the author ID with `get_queried_object_id()` on author pages :-)

Comment: Also, `get_posts` are in some instances easier to use than `WP_Query` as it already skips/exclude pagination and sticky posts and also ignore the `posts_*` filters :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Removed my statement about get_posts() to avoid confusion and added a note about get_queried_object_id() -- very nice!

Comment: I placed the code in author.php and it showed no comments at all. only the no comments found text.

Comment: Confirm if $user_id is set. Run **echo $user_id;** and see if it displays the user id of the user who you like to loop comments. Also confirm if this very user *has posted* any comments.

Comment: @ChristineCooper yes it did echo out a number and the author has made a few comments.

Comment: Can you please paste the content of your entire author.php file in: http://pastebin.com/ and provide me with a link so that I can have a look.

Comment: @ChristineCooper http://pastebin.com/xtqxC0p1

Comment: Thanks for the code, but to be honest, you have a big chunk of stuff there and the wp_comment_query() part could not be found. Can you please replace your author.php file with the following code and let me know if it works or not: http://pastebin.com/bBrG0M73

Comment: It still says no comments

Comment: Ok. Please try the following and report back if any comments were found: http://pastebin.com/QgzSyYgx This is a simple query for **any** comment. This is just to check that things are even working on your platform because both my solution and the one posted by @Abhik should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

First method, you are missing the second parameter for `get_the_author_meta`, which is the ID of the author.

Second method, you are using undefined variables.. Check this code, should get you what you want.

```
// Method 1
<ul class="authpcom">
    <?php
        $queried_object = get_queried_object();
        $author_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $queried_object->ID ); 

        $args = array(
            'author_email' => $author_email
        );
        $comments = get_comments($args);
        foreach($comments as $comment) :
            echo '<a href=" ' . get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . ' " rel="external nofollow" title=" ' . get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . ' ">' . get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '</a><br />' . $comment->comment_date . '<br /><li>' . $comment->comment_content . '</li>';
        endforeach;
    ?>
</ul>


// Method 2
<?php
    $comments = get_comments();
?>
<ul id="recent_comments">
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
<li>
    <p>
        <strong>
        <?php
            echo get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, '45' );
            echo strip_tags($comment->comment_author);
        ?>
        </strong>
        &nbsp;commented on <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ); ?>#comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" rel="external nofollow" title="<?php echo get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ); ?></a>: <?php echo wp_html_excerpt( $comment->comment_content, 45 ); ?> (...)
    </p>
</li>
<?php }  ?>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:** (09/05/2015)

```
// Method 1
<ul class="authpcom">
    <?php
        $authorID = get_queried_object_id();
        $author_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $authorID ); 

        $args = array(
            'user_id' => $authorID,
        );
        $comments = get_comments($args);
        if ( $comments ) {
            foreach($comments as $comment) {
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '" rel="external nofollow" title="' . get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '</a><br>' . $comment->comment_date . '<br>' . $comment->comment_content . '</li>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<li>No Comments from this Author</li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply however, the first method doesnt do anything and the second one does the same. It prints out all the comments made by everyone. This is on author.php.

Comment: @mygm26 the second method should display all the comments, regardless of the comment author as you are not passing any filter to get comment from any particular. However, the first method SHOULD work. Try the new code, I have added a check to see if it can find any existing comment from the author.

Comment: Still tells me no comments @Abhik

Comment: @mygm26 Can you post a var_dump of `get_queried_object()` of author.php? `function obj_check() {
 $queried_object = get_queried_object();
 var_dump( $queried_object ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'obj_check' );` Load any author profile page after adding this code and put the output in your original question?

Comment: ok will update now

Comment: @mygm26 The var_dump looks quite okay, edited my answer. Try now and let me know. If this still doesn't work, please do a pastebin of your entire author.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [ultimate member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/) plugin. It seems to be able to do a lot of things with user profiles, but also appears to be suitable to display user's comments on the profile page.

> Show author posts & comments on user profiles