# Get number of comments after modifying comment query

Tags: wp-query, customization, comments, wpdb

I have modified the comment query arguments in `comment-template.php` from

```
$author_id = get_query_var( 'author_id', 1 );
        $comment_args = array(
                'order'   => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'comment_date_gmt',
                'status'  => 'approve',
        );
    $comments = get_comments( $comment_args );
```

to the following code below

```
$author_id = get_query_var( 'author_id', 1 );
    if($author_id == '') {
        $comment_args = array(
                'order'   => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'comment_date_gmt',
                'status'  => 'approve',
        );
    }
    else { 
        $comment_args = array(
                'order'     => 'ASC',
                'orderby'   => 'comment_date_gmt',
                'status'    => 'approve',
                'meta_key'  => 'custom_author_id',
                'meta_value'=> $author_id,
            );
    }
    $comments = get_comments( $comment_args );
```

I would like to know how to modify the number of comments being diplayed i.e. `get_comments_number()`

Comment: Are you talking about modifying the core file `./wp-includes/comment-template.php`?

Comment: yes....i have modified that file

Answer (score 4):

> #### Refrain from editing core files
>
> WordPress was developed with extensibility in mind, and provides many ways to change the appearance and functionality of an installation without altering the WordPress software itself (mostly using [Hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters) in conjunction with [Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and [Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)). The software is comprised of it's "core files", which are generally everything outside of the `./wp-content` directory except `./wp-config.php`, and any directory-level server configuration files (`.htaccess`, etc.).
>
> Editing the core files of a WordPress installation is typically neither necessary nor maintainable, and as such is ***strongly*** discouraged unless you can find no other means to achieve your ends and are familiar with the consequences of doing so; these include automatic updates overwriting your changes, the WordPress community largely offering no support for your changes, and perhaps most importantly, **you run a much larger risk of introducing new security vulnerabilities into your WordPress installation**.

Rather than altering the core file [`./wp-includes/comment-template.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1113), a more maintainable solution would be to create [a `comments.php` template file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Comments_.28comments.php.29) within your custom theme (or [a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of your current theme if was developed by a third-party) and use [WP_Comment_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) in it to specify your new arguments. Use the `number` and `offset` arguments to specify a desired range of comments.

**Template File `./wp-content/themes/wpse202457_theme/comments.php`:**

```
<?php
  $author_id = get_query_var( 'author_id', '' );
  $comments = array();

  if( $author_id != '' ) {
    $comment_args = array(
      'order'      => 'ASC',
      'orderby'    => 'comment_date_gmt',
      'status'     => 'approve',
      'meta_key'   => 'custom_author_id',
      'meta_value' => $author_id,
      'number'     => 20, // Retrieve 20 comments...
      'offset'     => 40  // ...starting from the 40th comment.
    );
    
    $comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
    $comments = $comment_query->query( $comment_args );
  }
  
  
  if( ! empty( $comments ) ) {
    // The Comments Loop
    foreach( $comments as $comment ) {
      echo( '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p><br/><br/>' );
    }
  }
  else {
    echo( '<p>No comments found</p>' );
  }
?>
```

Check out [this excellent question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184449/wp-comment-query-pagination-delving-into-the-unknown) for the way to handle breaking comments up into pages (pagination) using the `number` and `offset` arguments dynamically. Dig into other themes' `comments.php` template file for some example markup.

Instead of creating a new theme template, you could alternately place your substitute comments template in a plugin, and use the [`comments_template` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) to redirect comment template inclusions to it:

**Plugin File `./wp-content/plugins/wpse202457_comments_plugin/wpse202457CommentsPlugin.php`:**

```
function wpse202457_comments_template( $comment_template ) {
  // Redirect ALL comment template inclusions to "./wp-content/plugins/wpse202457_comments_plugin/comments.php"
  return dirname(__FILE__) . '/comments.php';
}

add_filter( 'comments_template', 'wpse202457_comments_template' );
```

---

### ADDENDUM

In response to the comments, as @Rarst suggested, the `get_comments_query()` function will only return the number of comments recorded for the post object displayed in the main query.

To get the number of comments for your altered query, simply `count()` the results of the query, i.e.:

```
$comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comment_query->query( $comment_args );
$comment_count = count( $comments );
```

**However**, if you are using the `number` argument to specify the number of comments you wish to retrieve, then `$comment_count` will always be equal to, or less than `number`. To get the total number of comments that match your arguments, you will either need to omit the `number` argument and `count()` the results, or set the `count` argument to `true`, in which case the query will return the number of matching comments without returning the comments themselves:

```
$author_id = get_query_var( 'author_id', 1 );
$comment_args = array(
  'status'     => 'approve',
  'meta_key'   => 'custom_author_id',
  'meta_value' => $author_id,
  'count'      => true // Return the NUMBER of matching comments, not the matching comment objects themselves
);

$comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comment_count = $comment_query->query( $comment_args );
```

If you don't plan on doing anything else with the `WP_Comment_Query` object, you may want to create some convenience functions and put them in your plugin, or your custom theme's `functions.php` for quick access. Something along the lines of:

```
// Get comments with a custom_author_id meta-value of $author_id
function wpse202471_get_author_comments( $author_id = null, $args = array() ) {
  // If an author id was not passed, see if there's one in the query vars
  if( ! isset( $author_id ) )
    $author_id = get_query_var( 'author_id', null );

  // If no author id was provided, return a negative result
  if( ! isset( $author_id ) ) {
    if( isset( $args[ 'count' ] ) && $args[ 'count' ] )
      return 0;

    return array();
  }

  // Merge query argument arrays
  $comment_args = array_merge(
    array(    // Default values
      'order'      => 'ASC',
      'orderby'    => 'comment_date_gmt',
      'status'     => 'approve'
    ),
    $args,    // Any arguments passed to the function
    array(    // Merge meta-arguments last, so nothing can overwrite them
      'meta_key'   => 'custom_author_id',
      'meta_value' => $author_id
    )
  );

  // Perform the query and return the results
  $comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
  return $comment_query->query( $comment_args );
}

// Get the total number of comments with a custom_author_id meta-value of $author_id
function wpse202471_get_author_comment_count( $author_id = null, $args = array() ) {
  $args[ 'count' ] = true;
  
  // Remove query arguments that would prevent the proper count from being returned
  if( isset( $args[ 'number' ] ) )
    unset( $args[ 'number' ] );

  if( isset( $args[ 'offset' ] ) )
    unset( $args[ 'offset' ] );

  return wpse202471_get_author_comments( $author_id, $args );
}
```

Comment: This error is displayed `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null` on the line `$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );`

Comment: Thanks the code worked.....but how am i supposed to display the no of comments

Comment: Please help me with number of comments

Comment: i hope you are following with comments

Comment: Updated to add comment counting and a couple convenience functions under **ADDENDUM**

Comment: Thanks for the count and everything....But the comment box and all that style is not printing

Answer (score 0):

`get_comments_number()` does not rely on any comment query, it simply reports the number of comments stored persistently in post object (`comment_count` property).

You have omitted in your example how exactly query itself looks like. If you are using actual `WP_Comment_Query` object then its `comments` property will have array of results you could `count()`. If using API functions might get messier than that.

Comment: Is this the code....could you give me full fleged code